# Unable to boot a 64-bit Windows 7 even in safe mode

Tags: windows, boot, 64-bit

For the last 3 hours I've been trying to fix my laptop but I can't find anything.

Let me explain my problem: I recently deleted a Linux-type partition on my HDD which was about 100GB, then I tried to size up my Windows partition (with EaseUs Partition Master). The software told me that it have to reboot the computer and resize during boot. So well, why not, I rebooted, the software launched and displayed "Unable to mount drive" or something. Then the laptop rebooted again, and then... nothing.

When I launch Windows, it says that Windows can't boot and shows error 0xc0000225, that there are missing drivers and stuff, but no file is specified, and that I should pick my repair disc (which I haven't) and repair Windows. I don't have any installation disc either for my version, Asus isn't giving them.

Comment: Whats your laptop model number?

Comment: You have likely corrupted your boot drive, you will have to repair your installation, really the only way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a recovery/installtion DVD/USB for every OS you own.

When creating, deleting, moving, sizing partitions boot configuration data (in Linux and in Windows) is out of sync with partition addresses so boot will fail.

You should download or obtain a Windows installation image (iso) corresponding to installed Windows version and bit size (32 or 64 bit). Burn to DVD or USB and then run StartUp Repair.

See [how to download Windows 7 image and do startup repair](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindows7Booting.html).